# Matching numeric values in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

```
a <- c(4000,3500,3000)
b <- c(0.43,0.55,0.61)

test.data <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Let's say I want to get the value 0.55 by referencing 3500 instead of getting it by row/column. How would I achieve this? I think I could convert `a` to a string, then reference it that way, but is there a way to refer to the numeric value to extract the value in `b`?

Edit: Thank you all for your great responses!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood it well, you can get that as below:

```
test.data$b[test.data$a == 3500]
[1] 0.55
```

I would also like to introduce `dplyr` to you as you start your R journey:

```
library(dplyr)
test.data %>%
  filter(a == 3500) %>%
  pull(b)
[1] 0.55
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table`-

```
> setDT(test.data)[a==3500,b]
[1] 0.55
```

OR

```
> setDT(test.data)[a==3500]$b
[1] 0.55
```

**Note** - First, option is preferred as @Frank mentioned in the comment.

Comment: The first idiom is preferred since it doesn't create the subset of the data for all columns, just the one that's needed. Also, it checks exact match for the column name.

Comment: @Frank I agree. But, I was giving him more options.

Comment: When you give options, it's nice to talk about the differences and why one might prefer one to the other.

Answer (score 3):

More options.

```
test.data[, "b"][test.data$a == 3500]
# [1] 0.55

test.data[test.data$a == 3500, "b"]
# [1] 0.55
```

Comment: Another one: `with(test.data, b[a == 3500])`